# Getter Method coming up undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, https, es6-class

**I am having trouble with my getters coming back undefined when getting data from the API.  but when I hard code the data using my class the record and division record return just fine.  Does anyone know why the getter methods are coming back undefined when I call the api? See code examples below!!!**

### Model.js

```
export default class Nfl_team {
    constructor(team=String, name=String, wins=Number, losses=Number, ties=Number, win_percentage=Number,
         division_wins=Number, division_losses=Number, division_ties=Number, points_for=Number, points_against=Number) {
        this.team = team;
        this.name = name;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        this.ties = ties;
        this.win_percentage = win_percentage;
        this.division_wins = division_wins;
        this.division_losses = division_losses;
        this.division_ties = division_ties;
        this.points_for = points_for;
        this.points_against = points_against;
    }

    get record() {
        return [this.wins,this.losses,this.ties];
    }

    get division_record() {
        return [this.division_wins, this.division_losses, this.division_ties];
    }
}
```

### get_teams.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Nfl_team from '../models/teamModel.js';
import colors from 'colors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();


axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nfl/scores/json/Standings/2020?key=${process.env.API_KEY}`)
    .then(function (response) {

        /* Create a for each loop that goes over each obj and returns a new team object using NFL 
         team model with updated stats from sportsdata.io 
       __________________________________________________________________________________________*/

        response.data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(`Model for ${element.Name}: `.bold.brightBlue)
            console.log(new Nfl_team(element.Team, element.Name, element.Wins, element.Losses, element.Ties,
                element.Percentage, element.DivisionWins, element.DivisionLosses, element.DivisionTies,
                element.PointsFor, element.PointsAgainst));
            
            console.log(`record = ${element.record}`);
            console.log(`division record = ${element.division_record}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // always executed
    });
```

### terminal result

```
Model for Seattle Seahawks:
Nfl_team {
  team: 'SEA',
  name: 'Seattle Seahawks',
  wins: 9,
  losses: 4,
  ties: 0,
  win_percentage: 0.692,
  division_wins: 2,
  division_losses: 2,
  division_ties: 0,
  points_for: 393,
  points_against: 324
}
record = undefined
division record = undefined
Model for Arizona Cardinals:
Nfl_team {
  team: 'ARI',
  name: 'Arizona Cardinals',
  wins: 7,
  losses: 6,
  ties: 0,
  win_percentage: 0.539,
  division_wins: 2,
  division_losses: 2,
  division_ties: 0,
  points_for: 358,
  points_against: 303
}
record = undefined
division record = undefined
Model for San Francisco 49ers:
Nfl_team {
  team: 'SF',
  name: 'San Francisco 49ers',
  wins: 5,
  losses: 8,
  ties: 0,
  win_percentage: 0.385,
  division_wins: 2,
  division_losses: 2,
  division_ties: 0,
  points_for: 300,
  points_against: 311
}
record = undefined
division record = undefined
```

Comment: Because getters can't be serialised over JSON, they're just turned into regular properties. If you need an instance of a class, you've have to create one yourself.

Comment: `console.log(\`record = ${element.record}\`);` <-- `element` is not an instance of your class, it's one of the items returned by the API. You first need to do `const instance = new Nfl_team(...);`, and then this should work: `console.log(\`record = ${instance.record}\`);`

Comment: am I not creating a new instance of the class when I call new Nfl_team inside my foreach loop?

Comment: You create it inside a `console.log`, but you're not assigning it to a variable to use the getter on it

Comment: @blex Thank you so much! YOU ARE THE MAN

Answer (score 0):

We can't replicate the error without your API key but it certainly appears to me that there's a logical error in your code -- you're trying to use the methods of `Nfl_team` from the data you're getting from the service (which knows nothing about your code). I think it should look something like this:

```
response.data.forEach(element => {
    console.log(`Model for ${element.Name}: `.bold.brightBlue)
    
    const team = new Nfl_team(element.Team, element.Name, element.Wins, element.Losses, element.Ties,
                element.Percentage, element.DivisionWins, element.DivisionLosses, element.DivisionTies,
                element.PointsFor, element.PointsAgainst);
    
    console.log(team);
            
    console.log(`record = ${team.record()}`);
    console.log(`division record = ${team.division_record()}`);
});
```

Comment: @blex has already answered it for me!  I got it working!  thanks for trying though